# Unable to print multidimensional array in desirable string format dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm unable to print multidimensional array in desirable string format. I tried lot but didn't get the right string format.

**Here are the multidimensional array that I want to print dynamically:**

```
  $cars = array (
    array("Volvo",22,18),
    array("BMW",15,13),
    array("Saab",5,2),
    array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

**And here are the code that tried**

```
  $cars = array (
    array("Volvo",22,18),
    array("BMW",15,13),
    array("Saab",5,2),
    array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

  foreach ($cars as $car) {
    foreach ($car as $c => $v) {
        echo $v. '<hr>';
    }
  }
```

**Following is the desirable string format, that I want to get:**

> Volvo: In stock: 22, sold: 18.
>
> BMW: In stock: 15, sold: 13.
>
> Saab: In stock: 5, sold: 2.
>
> Land Rover: In stock: 17, sold: 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach ($cars as $car) {
        echo "$car[0]: In stock: $car[1], sold: $car[2] <hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    [$name, $stock, $sold] = $car;
    echo "{$name}: In stock: {$stock}, sold: {$sold}. <br>";
}
```

Comment: [Symmetric array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring)